# Check Point Firewall: "fw monitor" command to exclude certain traffic

Tags: firewall, checkpoint

In tcpdump, I can use `not` if I want to exclude it from the standard output.

```
tcpdump -i eth0 not port 22
```

Is it possible to accomplish the same task in `fw monitor` (Check Point firewall)?

I've been trying to exclude ssh (tcp/22) with these commands but the ssh port is still there in the output

```
fw monitor not ssh
fw monitor not port 22
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to [How to use FW Monitor](http://dl3.checkpoint.com/paid/a4/How_to_use_FW_Monitor.pdf?HashKey=1500448849_a857369c6d2f9e5b14767f02634a803b&xtn=.pdf) documentation:

> Command syntax
>
> ```
> fw monitor [-u|s] [-i] [-d] [-D] <{-e expr}+|-f <filter-file|->> [-l len] [-m
> mask] [-x offset[,len]] [-o <file>] <[-pi pos] [-pI pos] [-po pos] [-pO pos]
> | -p all > [-a] [-ci count] [-co count] [-vs vsid or vsname]
> ```

`-e expr` is the switch you're looking for:

> **fw monitor** has the ability to capture only packets in which you are interested in. It is possible to set the filter expression on the
>   command line (using the –e switch), read it from a file (-f) or to
>   read it from standard input (-f -).

The expression syntax documented as:

> fw monitor filters are using a subset of INSPECT to specify the
>   packets to be captured. The general syntax is:
>
> ```
> accept expression;
> ```

and then:

> Using relational and logical operators it is easily possible to build
>   complex capture filters. For example, **everything except http** expression:
>
> ```
> accept not (sport=80 or dport=80);
> ```

Therefore, the command you're looking for should be:

```
fw monitor -e 'accept not (sport=22 or dport=22);'
```

Comment: We should add a link to this fw monitor cheat sheet: http://www.roesen.org/files/fw_monitor.pdf